# Passing JSON with Django

Tags: django, json

I'm passing information to a Processing sketch from a Django backend.  The problem arises with "lectures", it seems that it is not serializable.  I'm missing something very basic methinks.

```
def get(request, last_update = None):
    timestamp = time.time() 
    if last_update:
        last_update = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(last_update))
        lectures = Lecture.objects.all().filter(datetime_edit__gt=last_update)
    else:
        lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
    updates = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'lectures': lectures}
    print updates
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(updates), mimetype="application/json")
```

Here is the response that I'm getting in the browser.

```
[<Lecture: whales>, <Lecture: cats>, <Lecture: rain>, <Lecture: china>] is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QuerySet` cannot be serialized in this manner. Use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) and `list()` to turn it into a basic Python structure (i.e. a `list` of `dict`s) first.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON serialize does not support serialization of arbitrary class instances.  You should convert Lecture records into dictionaries before serializing.